# How to use AngularJS 'controller as' syntax with multiple different controllers

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am new to javascript, typescript and AngularJS and am currently trying to learn the language by building a sample app.
I am an experienced programmer coming from an Actionscript / Flex background.

As I come from Actionscript I really like the 'controller as' syntax as I don't need to deal with the untyped $script object floating around and doing magic stuff that I can't control (my opinion as someone who distrusts javascript ;-).

In this example though I want to make an html page that displays loading info for a variety of different services that will load data. I envisage using this html fragment as a header at the top of a page which could show loading info for a list of albums, a list of images or even just when you're logging in.

This example is not what I would do in production as there are a number of things that I do not like about this approach but this is a learning exercise so I am trying to figure out how this would work.

I have the following TypeScript code:

**LoadingModule**

```
export interface ILoadable
{
    isLoading : boolean;
    isLoaded : boolean;
    loadingMessage : string;
    errorMessage : string;
}

export class LoadingController implements ILoadable
{
    //  Constructor

    constructor( private service? : ILoadable )
    {
    }

    //  Properties

    public get isLoading() : boolean
    {
        return this.service ? this.service.isLoading : true;
    }

    public get isLoaded() : boolean
    {
        return this.service ? this.service.isLoaded : false;
    }

    public get loadingMessage() : string
    {
        return this.service ? this.service.loadingMessage : "Loading...";
    }

    public get errorMessage() : string
    {
        return this.service ? this.service.errorMessage : "There was a fault.";
    }

}
```

**App**

```
app.config( ($routeProvider) => {
$routeProvider
    .when( '/albums', { templateUrl: './pages/albums.html' } )
    .when( '/album', { templateUrl: './pages/album.html' } )
    .when( '/pictures', { templateUrl: './pages/pictures.html' } )
    .when( '/loggingIn', { templateUrl: './pages/loading.html', controller : "loginController" } )
    .when( '/loadingAlbums', { templateUrl: './pages/loading.html', controller : "loadingAlbumsController" } )
    .when( '/404', { templateUrl: './pages/404.html' } )
    .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/loggingIn' } )
});
app.controller( "loginController", [ "authenticator", Picasa.LoadingController ] );
app.controller( "loadingAlbumsController", [ Picasa.LoadingController ] );
```

**Loading.html**

```
<div ng-controller="loginController as loadable">{{loadable.loadingMessage}}</div>
```

This all works great but I always get the loginController passed into the html page. This is obviously because I refer to it in the html page so this overrides me specifying a controller in the route provider setup.

My question is can I use the "controller as" setup in an html page that will have different controllers injected? 
I want the html page setup to work with an ILoadable.
I don't want to have to inject $scope into my controller and set properties on it.

Ideally I'd be able to inject a service directly into the html page so that I don't have to have the controller wrapper.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `controllerAs` syntax for the routing:

```
$routeProvider
    .when( '/loggingIn', { templateUrl: './pages/loading.html', controller : "loginController", controllerAs: 'login' } )
```

Your `Index.html` should have `ng-view=""` which is where the view will be substituted in.

This will enable you to do `{{login.message}}` in the views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this seems to be just what I am looking for but it's not working for me at the moment.

I have updated my routing controller but what do I put in my view? I have tried just ng-controller, ng-controller="as login" and ng-controller="loginController as login". I get errors in the console and {{login.message}} for the first 2 examples and the same controller in both views for the second option.

Comment: If you are using routing, you shouldn't need to use `ng-controller`. I updated my post above. You use `ng-view` which is used by the router.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to try it first to see if I could get it to work and I forgot to mark as answer. Thanks.